# Can't install OwnCloud

Tags: server, apt, downloads

I use Ubuntu Server 16.04 and want to install owncloud.

I found a tutorial for the configuration. So far it went pretty good but now I just can't install owncloud.
The commands on this [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3QWW.png) worked exactly the same way in my terminal. But when I run "apt install owncloud" afterwards it always shows the errors on the screenshot -->
[I tried apt and apt-get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLn98.png)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have created the Release.key file inside of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, but from your home directory, as shown in the screenshot. Please remove that file to get rid of the errors regarding the file extension.

Furthermore, you should run `apt-get update` after adding the owncloud repository. The screenshot just shows that the repository and it's key are added to apt, but that doesn't yet index the packages it holds.